# Немного о чистом коде

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

Приветсвую, есть у меня в коде класс ConfirmDialog, цель которого при нажатии кнопки Продолжить, выполнить действие, а при нажатии отмена, убрать диалог.

Вот код

```
/*
 * Created by k1ceargy on 30.11.18 (macOS 10.12)
 * */
public class ConfirmDialog {
        static Dialog dialog;

        public static void showDialog(final Context context, String msg, View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener) {
            dialog = new Dialog(context);

            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);

            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_dialog);
            final Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_continue);
            final Button cancelButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);

            text.setText(msg);
            dialogButton.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);

            cancelButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            cancelButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            v.getBackground().setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_yellow), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                            v.invalidate();
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                            v.invalidate();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
}
```

работает это так:

ConfirmDialog.showDialog(this, "Вы действительно хотите что-то сделать?", (сюда передается OnTouchListener на кнопку Продолжить (dialogButton)));

Так вот, у меня есть CheckBox в другом классе, и чтобы вставить в него галочку необходимо запросить подтверждение, ну а если нажата кнопка отмены необходимо вернуть исходное значение CheckBox. Вопрос в том, как это сделать, если на кнопку отмены не повлиять.

Если вешать 2 TouchListener то это уже хардкод. Поэтому и название такое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы что то много всего напутали. В Диалоге должно быть всего 2 кнопки (в вашем случае) ОК и ОТМЕНА, в случае отмены я так понимаю вам вообще делать ничего не нужно, оставляйте CheckBox в том состоянии в котором он есть.

Почитайте что такое делегаты и как с ними работать

в данном примере:
Создайте интерфейс например IConfrimDialog

```
interface IConfrimDialog {
    void onDialogConfirmClick();
    void onDialogCancelClick();
}
```

в метод showDialog вместо OnTouchListener передавайте ваш IConfrimDialog. Методы IConfrimDialog вызывайте в OnTouchListener (который создавайте в методе showDialog)

Реализуйте (создавайте) анонимный класс IConfrimDialog, там где сейчас создаёте OnTouchListener

*profit*

ну и еще, если вам нужно только менять CheckBox то почему бы его и не передать в ваш showDialog

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил убрать листенер и сделать так чтобы метод возвращал значение (`boolean` или кастомный енум).

```
public static DialogResult showDialog(final Context context, String msg)

enum DialogResult { OK, CANCEL }
```

Использовать так:

```
DialogResult r = showDialog(context, "");
if(r == DialogResult.OK) {
   // тут код для случая если пользователь нажал OK
} else {
   // а тут если нажал Cancel
}
```

Comment: можно по подробнее?

Comment: @k1ceargy добавил предлагаемую сигнатуру метода.

Comment: можете привести пример с кодом, не понимаю как это работает.

Comment: @k1ceargy добавил пример использования.

Comment: а как из OnTouchListener вернуть DialogResult?

Comment: Создать массив из одного элемента `DialogResult[] x = new {null}` , в листенере присвоить этому элементу значение `x[0]=DialogResult.OK`, а в конце вернуть `return x[0]`.

Comment: думает всегда что я нажал cancel

Comment: т.е в конце идет return, но не в onTouchListener, поэтому и возвращает нул, есть идеи?